# Extract localizable content from a HTML page

Tags: c#-4.0, localization

I need some advice on the best aproach to a feature I need to implement in a project I'm working on.

Basically, I need to be able to extract all localizable content (i.e. all the strings) from a HTML page. I really don't want to have to go and write a HTML parser. The application is written in C#.

Has anybody got any experience with this, or can anyone recommend an existing library that I could use to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to write your own parser. Fortunately somebody else already did that.
To parse HTML file, you can use [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

In this case you would receive Document Object Model, which you can walk just like any other DOM. Please find these examples:

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020001935/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/011211-1.aspx
http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home

And this question:

[How to use HTML Agility pack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/846994/247221)

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at this. BTW, your link above to HTML Agility Pack looks internal to Symantec ;-)

Comment: @Jimmy C: Yeap, somehow I've made a mistake. Fortunately that wasn't anything sensitive :)